# trying to make sense of the plot_acf() and plot_pacf() functions in stats-model

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am plotting ACF and PACF curves and not sure how to interpret the lags.

I am using the following function: statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf¶. It requires 'lag' as an argument. Let's say I set lag to 5. In my output graph, I see 5 bars with the confidence interval. I want to understand what lag 5 stands for in the acf graph.

Does it represent the correlation between lag 1 through lag 5? In other words, does it return the total correlation between lag 1 AND lag 5, lag 2 AND lag 5, lag 3 AND lag 5, lag 4 AND lag 5?

Please confirm that I interpret it right. Thank you.

Comment: Lag 5 is the correlation between Y(t) and Y(t-5).  This is true for any lag j, which is the correlation between Y(t) and Y(t-j).  These are the autocorrelations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)

Comment: I guess my main confusion was the fact that autocorrelation also implies that It accounts for the lags between the two time series data points, whereas the partial correlation only gives you the direct effect of two periods. Anyway - thank you!

Comment: You have it precisely backward. Autocorrelation is the simple correlation between Y(t) and Y(t-j) while partial autocorrelation is the correlation between Y(t) and Y(t-j) while controlling for Y(t-1), Y(t-2), ..., Y(t-j+1), the lags between the two.